# What is the effect of light on the boundary of a medium and vice versa?

Tags: magnetic-fields, photons, electric-fields, refraction

In an answer to a question about light refraction in different media [it was said](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/358285/46708):

> Light has an oscillating electric field, and if any charged particle is in the path of the light that particle will feel an oscillating force due to the oscillating electric field of the light. The result is that the wavefunction of the light becomes mixed up with the wavefunction of the charged particle.

I'm curious about the behavior of the mixed wavefunction when light passes the edge of a glass pane. In some distance away from the edge the interaction will be not really observable. But between this distance and the distance where the light goes into the glass what is going on?

Comment: Hi Holger, I am glad you posted this, as I had not seen John's answer. Can I make the suggestion, (ignore it if you like), that you be a little more precise about what it is you (and I) want to know. "What is going on" might be better phrased as a series of step by step walkthrough the interaction, especially how it ends and we get back, even for a tiny time (until the next interaction) to seperate wave functions. I guess you are asking in terms of a QM description, not a QFT description. If I am unclear, just ignore this.

Comment: @Countto10, hi. It would be nice if someone could give the result for say 2...5 electrons that get influenced when a photon flys by. What about phonon excitations?... How the path of the photon changes? -__  I'm uncertain because of this [answer of mine] (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362057/does-light-heat-transparent-mediums/362344#362344). Does a phonon excitation could take place without energy transfer at all? But this is another question. ____ Feel free to edit my question, changing "what's going on" to a better question.